# crossprod() in R syntax

Tags: r, cross-product

I'm trying to break apart the following code in the following function:

```
paired <- function(x) crossprod(x[x]-1:length(x))==0
```

For context, this appeared on [this answer in CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/187104/67822).

We have a matrix of ten 8-dimensional vectors corresponding to random permutations of the vector `1:8`

```
n <- 8
x <- replicate(10, sample(1:n, n))  

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    3    5    2    5    1    8    8     3
[2,]    4    3    5    4    3    8    5    2    1     8
[3,]    5    5    4    3    8    2    6    3    6     7
[4,]    6    8    1    7    4    3    8    6    2     2
[5,]    7    4    8    2    7    4    4    1    3     4
[6,]    2    6    2    6    5    1    3    4    7     6
[7,]    8    2    7    8    1    6    7    5    5     1
[8,]    3    7    6    1    6    7    2    7    4     5
```

And we apply column-wise the function `paired` with `apply(x, 2, paired)` getting the result of a boolean operation, which I guess assesses if any of the results of the `function(x) crossprod(x[x]-1:length(x))` equals zero:

```
intermediate <- function(x) crossprod(x[x]-1:length(x))
apply(x, 2, intermediate)
 [1]  74  80  88  88 100 108  26  90 124 106

apply(x, 2, paired)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The values in the `intermediate` call are not the dot product of the column vectors in the columnwise `x[x] - 1` with themselves, which for the first column would be:

```
> w <- c(1,4,5,6,7,2,8,3)
> v <- w[w] - 1
> t(v)%*%v
     [,1]
[1,]  140
```

Instead of `74`.

So the question is, what is the role of `length(x)` in modifying the `crossprod()`?

EDIT: Following the comments (thank you), if I try the code as:

```
w <- c(1,4,5,6,7,2,8,3)
v <- w[w] - 1:length(x)
t(v)%*%v
```

I get `crossprod(v) [1,] 146660` also different to `74`.

Comment: `-1:length(x)` not modifies the `crossprod`. It modifies `x[x]` So one can also write: `{ y <- x[x]-1:length(x); crossprod(y) }`

Comment: Thanks. So it turns the first column of the matrix into an 80-dimensional vector?

Comment: `1:length(x)` is a vector with the same number of elements as the matrix `x`. For `x[x]` it is a little bit tricky: it uses one-dimensional indexing of a matrix, the result is a vector and has the same length as the index `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't get too hung-up on the `crossprod` in the `paired` function. All it does is to check `x[x] - 1:length(x)` is a zero vector (i.e. the condition for "perfect pairing"). It could be coded differently and faster (see `paired2` or `paired3`):

```
> n <- 8
> set.seed(17)
> x <- replicate(1e6, sample(1:n, n))
>
> paired <- function(x) crossprod(x[x] - 1:length(x))==0
> paired2 <- function(x) sum(x[x]==1:length(x))==length(x)
> paired3 <- function(x) sum(abs(x[x]-1:length(x)))==0
>
> system.time(i.paired  <- apply(x, 2, paired))
   user  system elapsed
  9.812   0.000   9.821
> system.time(i.paired2 <- apply(x, 2, paired2))
   user  system elapsed
  4.548   0.000   4.550
> system.time(i.paired3 <- apply(x, 2, paired3))
   user  system elapsed
  4.617   0.000   4.617
>
> all.equal(i.paired,i.paired2)
[1] TRUE
> all.equal(i.paired,i.paired3)
[1] TRUE
```